# Tap is not detected on continuous scrolling of UICollectionView iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UICollectionView continuous scrolling using NSTimer, here is the code

```
let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.scrollToNextCard), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

func scrollToNextCard(){
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
                // I am changing the contentOffset of collectionview for continuous scrolling
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in

    })
```

When tapping on any of visible cells when scrolling is in progress, delegate's method **didSelectItemAtIndexpath** is not being called. How do I achieve tapping detection at the same time maintaining scrolling of collection view.  Please help thanks

Comment: Try `NSRunLoopCommonModes` instead of `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`.

Comment: No that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for the same, I had to add AllowUserInteraction flag on the animation block as in the code:

```
func scrollToNextCard(){
   UIView.animateWithDuration(Constants.CardFlowTimeInterval, delay: 0.0, options: [.CurveEaseInOut,.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
   })
}
```